# Keyboard doesn't disappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I added uitextfield programatically to uitableview cell, the problem is when I type on the textfield and click done or move from the textfield the keyboard doesn't disappear.

Any suggestion to solve that?

```
@interface test_20110605ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    UITextField *PtienttextField ;
}

@property ( nonatomic , retain ) UITextField *PtienttextField ;

@end

at m file 

@implementation test_20110605ViewController

@synthesize PtienttextField ;


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1 ) {


            //cell.textLabel.text = "Patient Name";



            UILabel *PatientLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 25)];
            PatientLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            PatientLabel.tag = 1;
            PatientLabel.text = @"Patient Name" ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PatientLabel];

            PtienttextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30)];

            PtienttextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
            PtienttextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            PtienttextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            PtienttextField.delegate = self;
            //PtienttextField.tag = 2 ; 
            [PtienttextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PtienttextField];
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{


    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean with "move from the textfield"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing the following in textFieldShouldReturn:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

then your `return YES;`

Comment: I added it and the same issue

Comment: Put a breakpoint or NSLog inside textFieldShouldReturn, is it definitely being hit?

Comment: It really should respond then... try if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) at the start of the textFieldShouldReturn: method and set a breakpoint in there on something.

Comment: i did , it enter the if statement and type nslog ny other suggestion

Comment: Okay, look into adding a target, as you would normally do with objects of this type: [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethodToHit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit]; Add this just after you create the textfield object. in myMethodToHit, either replace it with your textFieldShouldReturn: or write a quick method which takes in (id)sender as the textfield object.

Comment: @krypton I sent to you the sample code I test on your mail could u fix it for me

Comment: Try the suggestion in my previous comment.

Comment: execuse me I didn't understand your comment about add target specially the part of the function

Comment: Where you create the PtienttextField object and allocate memory to it, copy and paste the addTarget line I gave you and place it right under the alloc. The selector names the method that will be fired when the cell it clicked, so in my example it is called myMethodToHit. You can either keep this in which case the method signature will be -(void)myMethodToHit: (id)sender; where the sender is your text field... or: it should more likely fire off your textFieldShouldReturn: method instead, so place this name instead of myMethodToHit and see if it works.

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

 
 [textField resignFirstResponder];
 
    return YES;
} I was adding wrongly this line [textField resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

try putting a NSNotification when keyboard is appeared and set the textfield as firstresponsder. The problem you are using might be because of the textfield is not the first responsder in your case.